# Reactjs - proptypes check with oneOfType

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to allow a component to having one of two possible proptypes (string or undefined). I am using PropTypes.oneOfType to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Product.propTypes = {
    productTag: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string, undefined
    ]),
};

Product.defaultProps = {
    productTag: undefined
};
```

Is that the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Product.propTypes = {
    productTag: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.oneOf([undefined, PropTypes.string])
    ]),
};

OR

Product.propTypes = {
    productTag: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.oneOf([undefined])
    ]),
};

Product.defaultProps = {
    productTag: undefined
};
```

I think you can do it this way, by using `PropTypes.oneOf`. I don't think passing only `undefined` it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the property is undefined then that really means it isn't present, i.e., what you are trying to express is that the `productTag` property is optional, but when present it needs to be a string. Is that right?

As [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) states, "By default, these are all optional.". So in that case you can simply use:

```js
Product.propTypes = {
    productTag: PropTypes.string
};
```

since you are not marking it as `isRequired`.

Comment: So, if I wanted to render a element if the productTag not undefined and has value, like this.props.productTag && <span className="p__tag">{this.props.productTag}</span> This will work?

Comment: On this component will be used in several components as child and some of them not passing productTag props to this and that is my main purpose to add propstype and defautProps.